# WSO2 APIM How to subscribe application to all version of API?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm using WSO2-APIM 2.1.0 version.
I've set of API in `WSO2-APIM` as `Inventory` whose version is defined as `1.0.0`. Then I've created new version `2.0.0` of the same following process given in [link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Create+a+New+API+Version).
But now newer version don't have any applications subscribed to it.
Is there is a way to define whatever applications are subscribed to version `1.0.0` should also get subscribed to version `2.0.0`.

I do have around 10K applications, doing everything manually is pain. Let me know if there is workaround for the problem.

Comment: Hi @AshwinK , by default the same set of applications will be automatically subscribed to the newer version of API as well. After creating the 2.0 version, when publishing it, by any chance did you tick the checkbox 'Requires re-subscription when publishing the API'? If so, the behavior you have described is possible which in the sense we need to re-subscribe.